# Background page flashing

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

When user request any page. The request is authenticated by the `asp` page which is different web app.

If user is authenticated successfully, it serves the request page.

If authentication failed. Then user served with authentication page.

It all works well. But when it calls one page from another page, the called page flashes in background.

How  I can avoid this background page flashing. Any suggestions?

Comment: You've tagged this as Classic ASP and ASP.net.  Which is it?

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of redirect loop where when the final page is served up, it keeps redirecting back/to another page over and over again?